# What is wrong in this ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save some data to my database, using an Ajax-call, like i did hundrets of times before:

```
function saveNewGraphic() {
var svgString = drawObject.node().outerHTML;
if (logLevel >= 10) {
    console.log("svgEditor - saveNewGraphic");
    console.log("SVG-Grafik: " + svgString);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: appBaseUrl + 'Symbols/SaveNewGraphic',
    data: {
        svgString: svgString,
        pageId: pageId
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Fehler beim Speichern der neuen Grafik auf Seite (ID) " + pageId);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if (logLevel >= 10) console.log("Grafik mit ID: " + result.data.ID + " gespeichert");
        //  svg.attr("id", result.data.ID);
    },
    async: false
});
}
```

svgString is ok and pageId also.
I tried same without error, success and async but it even doesn't hit the Controller-Action.
Only Message:

```
HTTP500: SERVERFEHLER: Es ist ein unerwarteter Zustand aufgetreten, sodass der Server die Anforderung nicht erfüllen kann.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:52771/Symbols/SaveNewGraphic
```

This is the Action that should be hit:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleName.AdminOrEngineerOrSales)]
    public ActionResult SaveNewGraphic(string svgString, int pageId)
    {
        string message="ID fehlerhaft";
        //if (pageId == 0) message = "Neue Grafik wurde nicht gespeichert, Page-ID nicht lesbar" ;

        int id = 1;// SymbolDataProvider.SaveNewProjectGraphic(svgString, pageId, User.Identity.Name);
        //if(id >= 0) message = "Grafik erfolgreich gespeichert";


        var data = new { ID = id, Message = message };
        return Json(new { data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
    }
```

It is strange that this Action would be hit (of Course if I Change the url).

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleName.AdminOrEngineerOrSales)]
    public ActionResult SaveNewPosition(string positionData, int pageId, int id = 0, int symbolId = 0)
    {
        string message;
        if (id == 0)
            message = "Position nicht gespeichert, Id nicht lesbar";
        else if (SymbolDataProvider.SaveSymbolPosition(id, positionData, symbolId, pageId, User.Identity.Name))
            message = "Position gespeichert.";
        else
            message = "Position nicht gespeichert, Probleme beim Datenbankaufruf!";
        return Json(new { Message = message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
    }
```

But I could not see the difference between them.

Comment: Maybe the real error message is available in the Event Viewer?

Comment: I just came Closer to the Problem.  The svgString is (of Course) an svg-string like <line x='... ></line>.
This seems to be a Problem for the call.
If I try to Transport "Text" or "Hello World" the Action is hit.
So how can I call an Action and give it such a string as Parameter?

I'm afraid I don't know what you mean, Hans Kesting

Comment: try adding `contentType` and  `dataType`  as    `contentType: "application/json",dataType: "json",` in ajax

Comment: You mean like this?
`$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: appBaseUrl + 'Symbols/SaveNewGraphic',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            svgString: svgString,
            pageId: pageId
        },
...`

Doesn't work :(

Comment: This is the string of the svg: `<line class="hotwater graphic" x1="700" y1="-130" x2="50" y2="-330" />`

Comment: ok, if I remove the signs < and > it works. So there should be a way that I don't have to do this.

Comment: Try annotating the action with  [ValidateInput(false)]

Comment: try this: data: { "svgString": svgString, "pageId": pageId }

Comment: @SkyeMacMaster, [ValidateInput(false)] was the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Asp.net was seeing html-like input and blocked that as potentially dangerous. You however expect it here, so that validation can be disabled.